# Looping through a recordset to output Ms-Access report to a pdf file

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to get pdf file by `tenant_id` using `docmd.outputTo`. Unfortunately this routine produce output pdf file that all are in a same single `tenant_id`. If I remove `docmd.outputTo` last parameter `pathName & fileName` then it's require file name through dialogue and output file nicely filtered by `tenant_id`. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the query of invoice: `SELECT * FROM tblInvoice WHERE tenant_id = CurTenantID()`

```
Public Sub Output()
    Dim MyRs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rpt As Report
    Dim fileName As String, pathName As String, todayDate As String

    pathName = "C:\Users\abzalali\Dropbox\tenant_db\Invoice\"
    todayDate = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")
    Set MyRs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tenant_id, name, company, email FROM qryEmailClientList")

    DoCmd.OpenReport "Invoice", acPreview, , , acHidden
    Set rpt = Reports("Invoice")

    With MyRs
        .MoveFirst
            Do While Not .EOF
                fileName = "Invoice_" & todayDate & !tenant_id & ".pdf"
                rpt.Filter = "[tenant_id] = " & !tenant_id
                rpt.FilterOn = True
                DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Invoice", acFormatPDF, pathName & fileName
               .MoveNext
            Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DoCmd.OutputTo` lacks parameters for filtering, the best option is to base the report on a public function to get the current ID.

E.g.

```
' Function to both set and retrieve the current Tenant ID
Public Function CurTenantID(Optional SetTenantID As Long = 0) As Long

    Static TenantID As Long

    If SetTenantID > 0 Then
        TenantID = SetTenantID
    End If

    CurTenantID = TenantID

End Function
```

Your report uses this function in its record source, e.g.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tblInvoice WHERE tenant_id = CurTenantID()
```

And when generating the PDF reports in the loop, you use the `SetTenantID` parameter:

```
Public Sub Output()

    Dim MyRs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim fileName As String, pathName As String, todayDate As String

    pathName = "C:\Users\abzalali\Dropbox\tenant_db\Invoice\"
    todayDate = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")
    Set MyRs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT tenant_id, name, company, email FROM qryEmailClientList")

    With MyRs
        ' .MoveFirst -- unneeded after OpenRecordset()
        Do While Not .EOF
            fileName = "Invoice_" & todayDate & !tenant_id & ".pdf"
            Call CurTenantID(!tenant_id)
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "Invoice", acFormatPDF, pathName & fileName
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: it's not filtering yet, output all pages in the report.

Comment: Have you adapted the `Record source` of your report "Invoice"? If yes, please add it to your question.

Comment: Yes I added `Record source`

Comment: And have you also removed `DoCmd.OpenReport "Invoice", acPreview, , , acHidden` ? What happens if you open the report manually (after calling `CurTenantID(<an existing ID>)` ) ? @MirAbzalAli

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry I forgot to remove that, It fantastic treatment and perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use the [DoCmd.OpenReport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-openreport-method-access) method to filter report and then leave the report name blank in [DoCmd.OutputTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/docmd-outputto-method-access) as per the docs:

> ObjectName > Optional > Variant: If you want to output the active object, specify the object's type for the ObjectType argument and leave this argument blank.

```
With MyRs
    .MoveFirst
    Do While Not .EOF
        fileName = "Invoice_" & todayDate & !tenant_id & ".pdf"

        DoCmd.OpenReport "Invoice", acViewReport, , "[tenant_id] = " & !tenant_id, acHidden
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, , acFormatPDF, pathName & fileName
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: With this way it also works but report view showing during execution, I wanted to hide report view.

Comment: Go ahead and add *acHidden* for its *WindowMode* argument.