# MS Access 2013 VBA auto cancels OutputTo (Error 2501)

Tags: vba, ms-access, for-loop, pdf-generation, ms-access-2013

I am trying to configure a function that will automatically generate a folder of pdfs for a user based on the user inputting the report type they want and a file path they want to save. 
Some notes:

- It is generally used to generate ~100 pdf reports based on a query
  pulling data from a linked backend database table.
- CReport is a report name in the database programmatically assigned
- CPath is a folder selected using the file dialog
- Code runs perfectly fine multiple executions in a row if OutputTo line in code loop is commented out (unfortunately that is the whole point of this)

> Error 2501
>   appears between 2-76 loop repetitions in, rarely at the same point
>      twice. Occasionally, the entire things runs, but I cannot hand off
>      something that runs only occasionally. 
>    -

- Using Access 2013 on Windows 7.
- I have tried rebuilding the function, rebuilding the forms, decompiling, compact and repairing, adding a 2 second delay after outputting the report and changing where I put the close report command.

Current code:

```
Sub RunThatReport(CReport As String, CPath As String)
    'dimension variables
    Dim dbs1 As Database, rst As Recordset
    Dim Can8 As Double, vend As String
    Dim Location As String, CFilePath As String
    'create a filename
    Select Case CReport
        Case "rpt_Form-1"
            Location = "_Form-1.pdf"
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rpt_all_lines", acFormatPDF, CPath & "\Lines Required.pdf", False
        Case "rpt_Form-2"
            Location = "_Form-2.pdf"
        Case "rpt_Form-3"
            Location = "_Form-3.pdf"
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    'Get the AN8 of all lines
    Set dbs1 = CurrentDb
    Set rst = dbs1.OpenRecordset("tbl_all_lines_to_run", dbOpenDynaset)
    rst.MoveFirst
    'loop through the lines
    Do While Not rst.EOF
        If Not IsNull(rst!AN8) Then
            Can8 = rst!AN8 'I know this assignment is not actually necessary
            vend = Replace(Replace(Replace(Trim(rst!Name), "/", "-"), "\", "-"), ".", "")
            'CFilePath = CPath & "\" & vend & Location
            CFilePath = CPath & "\" & Can8 & Location
            Debug.Print vend & ": " & Can8 & " " & CFilePath 'This is my check to look at what was getting hung up
            DoCmd.OpenReport CReport, acViewReport, , "ABAN8 =" & rst!AN8 'open report only for that line type
            DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, CReport, acFormatPDF, CFilePath, False
            'DoCmd.Close acReport, CReport, acSaveNo
            'waiting (2) 'This was my delay function
        End If
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    dbs1.Close
    DoCmd.Close acReport, CReport, acSaveNo
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you already tried in a different machine?

Comment: Yes, I have tried on 2 machines and am getting the same error.

Comment: I notice you don't have any error traps -- which may be useful to log what report it fails on. I would: (a) add an error trap and capture to a file; (b) add a timer delay of .2 seconds before and after your "DoCmd.OpenReport". If that helps, then you can remove the full-time timer, trap the error in the error trap and issue a timer wait when it fails. Do you need to view each of these reports while running?

Comment: I had this same requirement, only for thousands of outputs. I couldn't do more than 5,000 per batch and I had 60,000+ records to run through (20 years worth of data). Never did figure out why and can only guess somehow memory was being occupied with something. This was a one-time process so did my dozen batch runs and done. Your code looks very much like mine and cannot see any cause for issue. I did not use a timer delay.

Comment: @June7  I'm curious - yours ran to 5,000 without fail, while the OP's code randomly fails. You say your code is similar, but do you issue the 'OpenReport' and no '.Close' for each of your 5,000?

Comment: I did close each report. I do wonder why OP shows that commented out.

Comment: Now is see the .Close outside the loop. Should be within the loop.

Comment: @Wayne G. Dunn
There is no need to view them at all. Opening the report was just the method I used to apply a parameter via VBA.

Comment: I see you updated your post to say you added a timer and a close, but your posted code does not reflect that. Do you have any VBA code ANYWHERE in your report?  Does this issue happen with all three of the reports you could run?

Comment: You could try [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47306097/3820271) for running `DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport` on a single-record report without using `DoCmd.OpenReport` before. But I have no idea if it will help.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Timer and close were steps tried before I got frustrated enough to post this code. I have updated to include them commented out. 
This issue only happens on reports 1 and 2, but given that report 3 is always run after the first two and is usually <5 of the 100 reports run at the same time the sample size is pretty small.
No reports have any VBA code.

Comment: One reason I suggested a timer BEFORE the 'OutputTo' was just in case there was some background delay after the 'OpenReport', the wait may correct that. Hopefully your timer wasn't just something like 'Do until Timer > PriorTime + nnn'. I echo what @Andre posted about how to avoid opening the report by using a function. Personally, I would: (1) Close each report; (2) Put the delay after the 'OpenReport'; and if those don't fix, then include Andre's suggestion.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Adding timer Before the "OutputTo' has removed any instance of the error. Now I am just getting an error for it being unable to open any more tables after running ~250. However, that is not the original question. Thank you.

Comment: Great. Now you can either play with decreasing the timer as small as possible or trap the error and then delay and resume. Re error opening 250 tables ( I think you mean reports?), did you already reinstate the CLOSE after EVERY output?

Answer (score -1):

It worked for years, but after changing to access365 it showed that problem. The solution to skip the line "docmd.openreport" before running the command "docmd.outputto"
showed the right result.

Comment: Try to avoid the "Thanks." impression. It could get your post misunderstood as not an answer, flagged and deleted. I think you might be referring to comment on the question above. It is fine to turn such a comment into an answer, even appreciated - at least by me. Just credit the comment author (or the author of whatever got linked, or both). Ideally turn the comment into an answer according to [answer].