# Split MS-Access reports into its respective pdf's

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf, split, ms-access-2016

```
Sub btnCreatePDF_Click()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim MyFilename As String
    MyPath = "D:\"
        MyFilename = "KS1.pdf"
    'Open report preview and auto-save it as a PDF
        DoCmd.OpenReport "Student By Classes", acViewPreview
        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "", acFormatPDF, MyPath & MyFilename, False 'Change false to true here to auto-open the saved PDF
    'Close the previewed report
        DoCmd.Close acReport, "Student By Classes"
End Sub
```

It was for use in MS Access to create a single pdf of reports (containing up to 11 pages) and works fine for what I needed. However, I now need to split the report into the 11 or so pages and create a pdf for each of the pages. Any idea how this can be done? Do I have to add any unique ID or something. Please can someone provide any details on this. How do I split 11 files with one page per file respectively

Please also provide the updated code.

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304589/looping-through-a-recordset-to-output-ms-access-report-to-a-pdf-file